# Repeat code simplification method

Tags: jquery

I'm practicing html.
The code must be too long and repeated.
Is there a simple way to reduce it?

Thank you.

```
$(".sbox1  #sim2_o").click(function(){
$(".sbox1 .ori").hide();
$(".sbox1 .cg2").hide();
$(".sbox1 .cg3").hide();
$(".sbox1 .cg1").hide();
$(".sbox1 .cg2").show();
 });
```

Is there any way to use sibling ()?

Because I have to use a lot of them.

[image]

```
I think you'd better watch it here.
<section class="section1">
<div class="swrap">

    <div class="sbox1">
        <img src="strap/sim1.jpg" alt="sim1.jpg" class="ori">
        <div class="cg cg1"><img src="strap/sim1.jpg" alt="sim1.jpg"></div>
        <div class="cg cg2"><img src="strap/sim2.jpg" alt="sim2.jpg"></div>
        <div class="cg cg3"><img src="strap/sim3.jpg" alt="sim3.jpg"></div>
        <p>Pingo Color Flower Set White</p>
        <p><span id="sim1_b" style="color:#69BDE1;">■</span>
        <span id="sim2_o" style="color:#FE7B52 ;">■</span>
        <span id="sim3_p" style="color:#F35B75 ;">■</span>  </p>

    </div><!-- sbox1 -->
```

Comment: $(".sbox1 .ori , .sbox1 .cg2, .sbox1 .cg3, .sbox1 .cg1").hide(); $(".sbox1 .cg2").show();

Comment: or can you give me your sample markup(HTML)?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: much better if you create a fiddle with your codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$(".sbox1  #sim2_o").click(function(){
    $(".sbox1 .ori, .sbox1 .cg2, .sbox1 .cg3, .sbox1 .cg1").hide();
    $(".sbox1 .cg2").show();
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to use sibling ()?
Because I have to use a lot of them.

Comment: I added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

Based on the HTML markup you provided, you can navigate to parent node and hide all `img` and `div` elements and show only the element which you want.

```
$(".sbox1  #sim2_o").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().find("img, div").not(".cg2").hide();
    //or
    $(this).closest(".sbox1").find("img, div").not(".cg2").hide();
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Thank you for your response, but it doesn't work.